# How do you keep scrollbars persisting in mobile devices?

Tags: angular, css, google-chrome, mobile, scrollbar

I am coding an application in Angular 4, and it is to be designed for both mobile and desktop use. If I am running this page on a mobile browser, Is there a way to keep the scrollbars from disappearing? I will be running this page exclusively in Chrome or Chromium (for a TS-7990 Touchscreen). Please see the image included.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not clear about your question,I am answering it from what I've got from your question.

If you need a scrollbar inside that "Manage test" card, then just write as follows:

```
.manage-test{
   overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```

Comment: I have that in the appropriate DIV where applicable. It looks fine in "Desktop" mode, but when using Chrome's dev tools to emulate a mobile environment, the scrollbars simply vanish until you move the DIV with a touch.